# iptables: block communication with others in same subnet

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a couple of devices in my subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.0/24) and would like to make sure that one of these devices (identified by MAC or IP) can only talk via the router (where I'd like to set up this rule) to the internet but not to others in this subnet. How can I do this using iptables?

Comment: The router would not be involved in communication between hosts on the same subnet, as host1 would ARP with the IP of host2, get the MAC for host2 from host2, and then chat directly with host2, leaving the router completely out of the loop. I guess you could fiddle with the network configuration on host1 so it only has a route to the router, and not to the network, but using a separate network or VLAN or something for the unique host would be more typical.

Comment: You can't do it with iptables, you may want to use ebtables instead.